# can create a shared libxml2

Tags: makefile, android-ndk, java-native-interface, libxml2

i am creating an application in android using ndk and jni.In my app i have requirement to parse xml data.for which i have used libxml2.

when i am making a static library of libxml2 and use,it works fine.

But when i am trying to make a shared library and use it in my application i am getting errors while doing ndk-build:

```
undefined reference to `xmlReaderForMemory'
/home/subrat/EclipseIDE/workspace/jni/source/interface.c:677: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderRead'
/home/subrat/EclipseIDE/workspace/jni/source/interface.c:680: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderNodeType'
.......
```

so can any one please tell me whethet i am having any issue in my coding or i can't make shared library of libxml2..

any type of suggestions are appreciated........

Comment: yes, it is possible to create a shared libxml2.so

Comment: We need more info, e.g. the command you used to obtain this error (or a more extensive log). How did you build the shared libxml2?