# can i use a static library (lib***.a) in my androidndk application

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, static-libraries

after searching a lot, i am still unable to find one thing that whether can i use a lib***.a in my .java file or not.

```
i.e:
static {
    // Library
    System.loadLibrary("***");
}
```

i got this doubt when i read the line `You must provide a native shared library that contains the implementation of these methods` in the overview.html.

so can any one tell me whether can i use lib***.a in .java file or not.

If yes then how?

since `you should not use the 'lib' prefix and '.so' suffix here.` is written in the overview.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can't. As far as I know, the Java native interface uses dynamic libraries to load code runtime; I'm sure that cannot be done with archive libraries (.a).

Comment: then to include a lib***.a in my .java what should i do without creating lib***.so

Comment: @Subratnayak. you should create a .so. If you can't, really, then you'll have to fall back to entirely native (C-only) development ans properly static link the .a file to your final executable.

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in the `android-ndk/docs/overview.html` 
that You `must` provide a `native shared library` that contains the implementation of these methods, which will be packaged into your application's .apk.
So I suppose you have no alternative.

Comment: @H2CO3 I would like to know how can i link C archive to Android Source. As per my information this can be done using Android NDK which is the legitimate solution.

Comment: @nimish by creating an .so. you can't 'link' a static archive to a compiled java class as they're of different formats.

Comment: @H2CO3 Oh my bad :) the question was that If I have a C Archive you mentioned that I'll have to fall back to entirely native (C-only) development ans properly static link the .a file to your final executable. SO wanted some more details on that ?

Comment: @nimish nothing special, really. You can link static libraries on Abndroid as you would do on any other Linux-based system.

Comment: @H2CO3 can u answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735969/can-create-a-shared-libxml2 plz........